# Using the Office UI fabric

Tags: design, guidelines

We are designing an Office Add in, and a question came up. 
Does the design needs to be in 100% correlation to the Office UI Fabric?
In terms of Color, Icons and Typography ?

Thanks,

Comment: Microsoft Office? If yes, there are guidelines for that: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-design

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a licensing issue.

Comment: Not at all.
If the answer was that is was mandatory- than yes.
But if its debatable, than its a different question.

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if it mateches with the UI. Its a good UX.

For example, when I use Photoshop extensions or plugins, it comes with their own UI, Which makes me think that accidently I opened a different application.

If you follow the same UI design guidlines that will sync with  the application.

Comment: 1. The layout is according to the add in define by Microsoft, so no confusion can occur there.

Yes, also- think about the branding - the guideline defines very specific color and typography that can be far away from the brand...
See- http://dev.office.com/fabric/styles

Again- to the main question- should it correlate 100%?